# issue in form validation in php?

Tags: php, validation

I have a form with several fields and with 4 radio buttons. Based on this radio button click, the form has to be validated. All the fields in the form need not be validated.

Check this link, the similar thing I want:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396119/i-have-issue-in-php-validation-for-nested-if-else-condition

The code i tried:

```
<?php
        $guestname="";$validguestname="";
    $guestno= "";$validguestno="";
    $nochild= 0;$validnochild="";
    $noadults=0;$validnoadults="";
    $infants =0;$validinfants="";
    $noofperson ="";$validnoofperson="";
    $check_in="";$validdate1="";
    $check_out="";$validdate2="";
    $noofnight = "";$validnoofnight="";
    $room_type="";$validroom_type="";
    $nfroom="";;$validnfroom="";
    $noofextrabed ="";$validnoofextrabed="";
    $roomarray="";$validroomarray="";
    $mealplan="";$validmealplan="";
    $rateperday ="";$validrateperday="";
    $rateperbed ="";$validrateperbed="";
    $total_amount ="";$validtotal_amount="";
    $advance   = "";$validadvance="";
    $balance   ="";$validbalance="";
    $receiptno ="";$validreceiptno="";
    $dateofremitance ="";$validdateofremitance="";
    $bankorcash="";$validbankorcash="";
    $bank_name="";$validbank_name="";
    $bookedby="";$validbookedby="";
    $paymentmode  ="";$validpaymentmode="";
    $bookingtype="";$validbookingtype="";
    $reservationstatus="";$validreservationstatus="";
    $book_by="" ;$validbook_by="";
    $agentname= "";$validagentname="";
    $agentphoneno="";$validagentphoneno="";
    $error_message="";$error_message1="";$error_message2="";
    $date3=date('Y-m-d');
   if(isset( $_POST['submit']))
   {            
    $guestname= $_POST['guest_name'];
    $bookingtype=$_POST['booking_type'];echo $bookingtype."helooo";
    $guestno= $_POST['guest_no'];
    $reservationstatus=$_POST['reservation_status'];
    $nochild= $_POST['no_child'];
    $book_by= $_POST['bookby'];
    $agentname= $_POST['bookbyother'];
    $agentphoneno= $_POST['phone1'];
    $noadults= $_POST['no_adults'];
    $infants = $_POST['no_infants'];
    $noofperson = $nochild+$noadults+$infants;
    $check_in=trim( $_POST['checkin']);
    $check_out=trim( $_POST['checkout']);
    $noofnight = $_POST['no_of_days'];
    $room_type= $_POST['roomtype'];
    $nfroom= $_POST['noofroom'];    
    $noofextrabed = $_POST['no_of_extra_bed'];
    $roomarray= $_POST["room_no"];
    $mealplan= $_POST['meal_plan'];
    $rateperday = $_POST['rp_day']; 
    $rateperbed   = $_POST['extrarate'];
    $total_amount =  $_POST['totalamount'];
    $advance   = $_POST['advance_amount'];
    $balance   = $_POST['val_username'];
    $receiptno = $_POST['receipt_no'];
    $dateofremitance = $_POST['date_remitance'];
    $bankorcash= $_POST['paymentmode'];
    $bank_name= $_POST['bankname'];
    $booking_date=date('y-m-d');
    $bookedby= $_POST['adminbooking'];
    $paymentmode  = $_POST['payment_mode'];
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($check_in));
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($check_out));
///1st condition///
    if($bookingtype=="direct" && $reservationstatus=="H" && other_conditions)
    {

        insert query;

    }
    ///2nd condition///
    else if($bookingtype=="direct" && $reservationstatus=="C" && othercondition for particular fields)
    {insert query;}
    ///3rd condition///
    else if($bookingtype=="agent" && $reservationstatus=="H" && $book_by=="other")
    {echo "agent anfd holding and other";}
    ///4th condition///
    else if($bookingtype=="agent" && $reservationstatus=="H" && $book_by!="other")
    {echo "agent anfd holding and not toher";}
    ///5th condition///
    else if($bookingtype=="agent" && $reservationstatus=="C" && $book_by=="other")
    {echo "agent anfd confirm and other";}
    ///6th condition///
    else if($bookingtype=="agent" && $reservationstatus=="C" && $book_by!="other")
    {echo "agent anfd confirm and not other";}
    //else condiition
    else
    {echo "choose ur option";}
```

Comment: please help im stuck for past several days...please and thanks in adv...

Comment: Your problem is with if and else's? I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: What happens and what do you want to happen?  Any errors?

Comment: u c d pic from the link i provided...in tat if direct and holding radio button is clicked then the fields other than disabled should be checked whether it is empty or not and ,if not empty then insert the datas into the database.....

Comment: if($bookingtype=="direct" && $reservationstatus=="H" && other_conditions) {insert query;} when i tried like this , i'm getting an unindexed error for other fields....since there are no values for that fields...

Comment: any ways to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, your problem seems to be figuring out the full range of values that have been entered on the first. You can try one of two approaches.

1. Get your form values default options if they have not been entered by the user. As an example:

```
if (!empty($_POST['')) {
    $reservationstatus=$_POST['reservation_status'];
}
else {  
    $reservationstatus=false; 
}
```

then your following query will work:

```
if($bookingtype=="direct" && $reservationstatus=="H" && other_conditions)
{
    your_query_here();
}
```

2. Check explicitly for entered values, but this makes for a more complex check.

```
if( ((!empty($_POST['booking_type']) && 
    ($_POST['booking_type']=="direct") )  && 
    ((!empty($_POST['reservation_status']) && 
    ($_POST['reservation_status']=="H") )  && 
    other_conditions)
{
    your_query_here();
}
```

Comment: if (!empty($_POST[''])){ }......where to chck it....while submitting the form ie if(isset($_POST['submit']))...do u get me...